# How do I reference a shell variable and arbitrary digits inside a grep regex?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am looking to translate this regular expression into grep flavour:

I am trying to filter all lines that contain `refs/changes/\d+/$VAR/`

Example of line that should match, assuming that `VAR=285900`

```
b3fb1e501749b98c69c623b8345a512b8e01c611    refs/changes/00/285900/9
```

Current code:

```
VAR=285900
grep 'refs/changes/\d+/$VAR/' sample.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what doesn't work?

Comment: I don't see a regular expression. Use the `-F` argument to `grep` in that case.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: How was anybody supposed to give a good answer before you edited the question to include the important `\d+` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to filter all lines that contain `refs/changes/\d+/$VAR/`

That would be

```
grep "refs/changes/[[:digit:]]\{1,\}/$VAR/"
```

or

```
grep -E "refs/changes/[[:digit:]]+/$VAR/"
```

Note that the `\d+` notation is a perl thing. Some overfeatured greps might support it with an option, but I don't recommend it for portability reasons.

Comment: I would not say that supporting perl regexes like GNU grep is overfeatured. Actually it is nice to have sometimes. But yes, for portability reasons I also won't recommend to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

> inside simple quotes I cannot use variable expansion

You can mix and match quotes:

```
foo=not; echo 'single quotes '"$foo"' here'
```

> with double quotes it does match anything.

It's not clear what you're doing, so we can't say why it doesn't work. It should work. There is no need to escape forward slashes for `grep`, they don't have any special meaning.